# Table header/body width issue

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table which has a header row and few rows for the body content.

Now these are actually 2 separate tables:

1. for Header
2. for Body content (which is part of another iframe)

I want that the widths should be same for the column header and it's corresponding body content.

How can I ensure that both the widths are similar and the appearance would be similar as if they are part of the same table?

I am open to both CSS or Javascript fix..

Note: I'll not be able to use fixed col widths AND neither do I have control to merge into one table...

Comment: I know this doesn't answer you question, but would you be opposed to using an Ajax request instead of an iframe so you can have it be a single table? I just want to make sure that's not an option before you try and hurt yourself. :-P

Comment: Can you just fixed width on all the columns? Otherwise you'd have to do cross-iframe javascript, which can be a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this? This will make your tables act as if thay where one

```
    var table1 = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var table2 = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    var tr = merge([table1,table2]);
    var padding = 2; //set your padding to make up for difference from offsetwidth vs style width

    var higestWidth = new Array();
    for(var i in tr){
        for(var j in tr[i].childNodes){
        var td = tr[i].childNodes[j];
        if(typeof td == 'object'){
            if(higestWidth[td.cellIndex] == null || higestWidth[td.cellIndex] < td.offsetWidth){
            higestWidth[td.cellIndex] = td.offsetWidth;
            }
        }
        }
        for(var j in tr[i].childNodes){
        var td = tr[i].childNodes[j];
        if(typeof td == 'object'){
            td.setAttribute('width', higestWidth[td.cellIndex] - padding);
            }
        }
        }
```

Almost forgot im using some of my own functions here, here thay come aswell

```
        var foreach = function(object,loop){
        for (var key in object) {
            if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            loop(object[key],key);
            }
        }
    }
    var merge = function(objectCollections){
        var array = new Array();
        foreach(objectCollections,function(objectCollection){
            foreach(objectCollection,function(object){
                array.push(object);
            });
        });
        return array;
    }
```

Comment: Thx a lot..i assume urs is a generic solution and should work for any col widths..i'll also try the same..thx again..

Comment: HTMLTableElement.rows may be of interest to to you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.rows

Comment: Just one quick question..The merge function..is it just calculating the greater width and setting accordingly or is it kind of doing some merging...

Comment: It is just a function to merge two objectCollections (or more) in to one array sinse it cant be done with concat :)

Thanks alot Matt McDonald i got something similar in my lib files, but i havent managed to make it work in ie6 yet.

Comment: For some reasons, I am getting an error td.setAttribute is not a function for the line td.setAttribute("width", higestWidth[td.cellIndex] - padding); ....i.e even though it passes the condition for if(typeof td == 'object')

Comment: Thats really strange, i tryd this code before posting it.. maybe you can show abit more of your code, might be something else

Comment: Yes sure..you can have a look at http://ipad.atwebpages.com/table/try.html Try opening in Firefox..Basically I am trying to align the columns for date "05/24/2011" and the corr values below it..

Comment: try to use this;var table1 = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  var table2 = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[1].contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('tr');

Comment: I tried the code...But am still getting the same error..You can see the updated code on the same page..http://ipad.atwebpages.com/table/try.html

Comment: can you console.log(td); on the same page and let me watch it, do it right after if(typeof td == 'object'){

Comment: okey, try to change the if statement to (typeof td == 'object' && typeof td.attributes != 'undefined')

Comment: ok..tried that now..still get the same issue..you can check it on the same page..

Comment: In fact also tried this...if (typeof td == 'object' && typeof td.attributes != 'undefined' && typeof td.attributes != null)

Comment: Also for the merging, I have changed table2 to use ('iframe')[2]

as that is the one I want to merge....So the date column is header and immediately below it are the corr columns..

Comment: the mergin isnt on the table or iframe its the array of trs thats beeing merged, this problem make no sense, can u comment the row to setAttrebute and log the td instead? will show us what elements we found

Answer (score 0):

If it is not important that the table be "fluid", you can define classes for each of your columns and style them with css. Ex:

```
.col-username { width:150px; }
.col-email { width:200px; }
```

and so on.

Edit: [here](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) is an example I just found that uses CSS to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of agree with Rodrigo, although I would set max-width and min-width, rather than just width like so:

```
.col-username { 
     max-width:150px;
     min-width:150px;
}
.col-email { 
     max-width:200px;
     min-width:200px;
}
```

Otherwise, the actual size can depend on the table cell content and available space.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using `<thead>` and `<tbody>` if you can.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1 / Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 1 / Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 1 / Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 2 / Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 2 / Col 2</td>
      <td>Row 2 / Col 3</td>
    </tr>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Unless there's a reason you have separate tables, it would be much simpler to do it this way.